# Select Customer Count in Consecutive two days in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have Table of Transactions which Stores Customer Transactions data,Table like below.

```
ID     CustomerID    Transaction Date           
1       C001               01/07/2017         
2       C001               01/07/2017
3       C001               01/07/2017
4       C001               02/07/2017
5       C002               02/07/2017
6       C001               15/07/2017
7       C001               15/07/2017
8       C001               16/07/2017
9       C001               17/07/2017
```

I want to select Count of customerId from Transaction of consecutive 2 days with in month.like select count of customer with date between **01/07/2017 to 02/07/2017 , 02/07/2017 to 03/07/2017** etc.

Result Should be like this.

```
      count   CustomerID    fromDate     toDate           
        4        C001      01/07/2017  02/07/2017
        3        C001      15/07/2017  16/07/2017
        2        C001      16/07/2017  17/07/2017
        1        C001      17/07/2017  18/07/2017
```

Edit: Usable Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (ID int, CustomerID char(4), TransactionDate Date);
GO
INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES
(1,'C001','20170701'),         
(2,'C001','20170701'),
(3,'C001','20170701'),
(4,'C001','20170702'),
(5,'C002','20170702'),
(6,'C001','20170715'),
(7,'C001','20170715'),
(8,'C001','20170716'),
(9,'C001','20170717');
--DROP TABLE #Sample;
```

Comment: What if the customer only came on the 23rd and there is no next day?

Comment: select count of 23rd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could come as this close to your requirement

Actually, there is a problem with your desired output
please consider ID=5 case and ID=9 case too

```
; with cte as (
    select
    distinct
    CustomerId,
    PrevDate = dateadd(dd,-1,TransactionDate),
    TransactionDate,
    NextDate = dateadd(dd,1,TransactionDate)
    from #Sample
)
select 
    customerId, TransactionDate, NextDate,
    (
        select count(*) 
        from #Sample t 
        where 
            t.customerId = cte.customerId and
            t.TransactionDate between cte.TransactionDate and cte.NextDate
    ) as cnt
from cte
where
    ( 
    exists (select * from cte as t2 where t2.customerId = cte.customerId and t2.TransactionDate = cte.NextDate)
    )
    or
    (
    not exists (select * from cte as t2 where t2.customerId = cte.customerId and t2.TransactionDate = cte.NextDate)
    and
    not exists (select * from cte as t2 where t2.customerId = cte.customerId and t2.TransactionDate = cte.PrevDate)
    ) 
order by customerId, TransactionDate
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `lead()`:

```
select customerid, tdate as from_date, next_tdate as to_date
from (select t.*, lead(tdate) over (partition by  customerId order by tdate) as next_tdate
      from (select distinct customerId, tdate
            from transactions t
           ) t
     ) t
where next_tdate is not null;
```